# backspace regex gets returned to end of regex array value on input

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, regex

I have an input and this input has a limit of 10. If the user were to delete or backspace one of the numbers in the middle of the number array, the cursor or backspace line is now at the end of the array rather than where the user first selected the backspace to be placed. I would like it so that when the user selects this array of numbers, and wants to delete two of the numbers in the middle, they can do so without the backspace cursor jump to the end of the number array. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7Lj82e5y/1/)

HTML

```
<div>
<input type="text" id="test" name="test" style="width: 210px;" maxlength="10" />
</div>
```

JS

```
var y =  function (e) {
            var x = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/);
            e.target.value = !x[2] ? x[1] : x[1] + x[2] + (x[3] ? x[3] : '');
            var last = x[3];
            };    
            document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('input', y);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remember position, then update the position after complete your operation.

[Working Demo link](https://jsfiddle.net/7Lj82e5y/3/)

```
var y = function(e) {    
  var target = e.target;    
  var x = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/);
  var value = !x[2] ? x[1] : x[1] + x[2] + (x[3] ? x[3] : '');

  if (value === e.target.value) {
    return;
  }

  var position = target.selectionStart;
  e.target.value = value;      
  target.selectionEnd = position; // set the cursor on desired position.
};

document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('input', y);

//In order to avoid jumb behaviour when press non-numeric like a-z
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
  if (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```